# Infinite inclusion of stdio.h

Tags: c++

error:
2   2   C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\stdio.h   [Error] invalid preprocessing directive #inclu

1       C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\stdio.h                    from C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/stdio.h

I write a short code, but my code gives an error I've just started software, help please

deleted and reinstalled but did not work

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   cout << "Hello, world!";
   return 0;
}
```

I expected it to work, but it didn't[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dz9xj.png)

Comment: There's a possibility that you've got some weird characters in your source file. Delete the line which says `#include <iostream>` and copy/paste it from this comment.

Comment: Please look at `stdio.h`. It looks like you added a line with `#inclu` or `#include <stdio.h>`. Remove it.

Comment: in the `stdio.h` you have a `#inclu` directive thats what the error says find it and make it `#include`

Comment: You seem to have accidentally edited the file (possibly deleted the rest of the line) – at very first, you should restore the file to its original version, then to prevent similar errors, you maybe want to write-protect the include directory.

Comment: _@Can_ Find a better title your your question please!

Answer (score -1):

It sounds more like an error of your compiler. Your code ist basically right.